# definition of Smirnov class

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

The Smirnov class in the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ can be characterized as space 
$$ N^{+}=\{ \phi/\psi\; :\; \phi ,\psi\in H^{\infty},\; \psi\;\; outer\}  $$ 
where $H^{\infty}$ denotes the algebra of bounded analytic functions on $\mathbb{D}$.

> My **question** is what the meaning of ***outer*** is inside of the
>   brace?

Comment: See Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_. Or Duren _Theory of $H^p$ Spaces_. Or Garnett _Bounded Analytic Functions_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $\psi\in H^1(\mathbb{D})$ is called *outer* if it has the integral representation
$$
\psi(z) = \alpha \exp\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{it} + z }{e^{it}-z} k(t)\,dt\right)
$$
for some constant $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=1$ and some real-valued $k\in L^1[-\pi, \pi]$. The main features of outer function:

- $\psi$ does not vanish in the unit disk
- It also "does not vanish too much on the boundary". Precise meaning: $|\psi|$ has boundary limit values a.e. on the boundary, and $\log|\psi|$ is integrable (because it's $k$). So for example $\exp(1/(1-z))$ is not an outer function: it tends to $0$ too fast as $z\to 1$.

The main purpose of these is the inner-outer factorization: every $H^1$ function is the product of an inner function (modulus $1$ a.e. on the boundary) and an outer function, in an essentially unique way; you can only move a unimodular constant from one factor to the other.

Also, the reciprocal of an outer function has integral representation
$$
1/\psi(z) = \alpha^{-1} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{it} + z }{e^{it}-z} k(t)\,dt\right)
$$
which makes it somewhat manageable, even though $1/\psi$ need not be in a Hardy class. This is why having an outer functions in the denominator, as is the case in your formula, still makes a reasonable function class.